# How to verify client-side text in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm building a to-do list and one of the problems I'm facing is verifying that the correct to-do is checked off. I thought of using unique IDs for each and every to-do but a user can simply change the ID to that of another task. What can I do to make sure that the user does not temper with the checking off of tasks?

My flawed process:

User checks off task --> get task ID --> match ID on the backend

EDIT:
All the tasks are created beforehand. And user does not have the ability to create new ones.

Comment: then also check if the to-do is created by that user. And add user-id to your backend.

Comment: I apologize for not mentioning that all these tasks are created beforehand. I'll edit my post

Comment: well, I think you should not give access to the user to change the id. well, he can update the task but it is something sacred. for my todo list app, I used mongoose and mlab the id assigned where unique itself and I did not give any access such to the user. His playfield was limited. you can check out NetNinja youtube videos. it uses the same stack and same approach.

Comment: So a user can view source, change ID and .... and what. Who cares. It's not *your* to-do list. If the real concern is deleting someone's else todo item - by ID, than you're doing something totally wrong. Do you have a table where you join item ID by user ID?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan that's a very good point. So where should I draw the line when trying to make my app secure?

Comment: @A.Diaz I have no clue about your app architecture, what do you use for storing users? What do you use as database?

Comment: I'm using mongodb

Answer (score 0):

If this is ever touching your backed server, you should always assume your users are sending you garbage data or trying to hack your system.

In short: Always Validate Inputs from an untrusted source.

Some languages, i.e., C#, offer model validation as part of the processing pipeline, so some initial model validation by the time it reaches your action/controller.

In this case, the user sends you an ID and an action to do with the task:

```
{
   Id: "15f52b9f-3a09-4e56-adcf-c837ca4c92eb",
   Status: "completed"
}
```

You should validate:

1. The Item Exists.
2. The item belongs to the user
3. The user has permission to edit this item
4. The status is a valid type (they could send you "blah" as a status)

If any of these fail, you send an error message to the user (or 400 error and a message telling them whats wrong)

Edit: After reading some comments below:

There is one simple rule. Never trust the user, the user input or anything you cannot 100% control.

In the world of web, never trust anything in, around, or sent from the browser. The user has complete control over it including cookies, DOM, localstorage etc.

When handling user input, **always** validate it on the server **no exceptions.**

You can always double validate, i.e., validate on the client side and on the server side, but the client side is limited to basic business rules of the data or data format (example, MM/DD/YYYY format for dates or numbers must be less than 1000)

You can do them on the front end, but you STILL need to validate them on the back end.

Comment: I have a question in regards to this. What about viewing content? For example, only certain users can view ADMIN functionality if id in the database is equal to id for the admin. Whats stopping a user from going into the URL and modifying the id and setting it equal to id relating to admin thus revealing content relating to ADMIN functionality?

Comment: @InoCuro id should be from JWT or such, not a passed id.

Comment: I'm not using JWT unfortunately. I used localstorage and basically said if this localstorage id == 'admin' reveal the content but I was thinking this can be harmful if user has access to modify localstorage correct?

Comment: localstorage is not secure, and it can be modified easily, the only thing you can trust is a signed id, like one in JWT, or session cookie (cookie values are signed)

Comment: @InoCuro you should be using an authorization/authentication scheme. Generally this is in the form of a cookie. Yes someone can use someone else's cookie, or click jacking but then there are anti-forgery keys you can use.  Also, the cookies have expiration date and are validated on the server side for getting the user name, roles/claims. You should not use a super user "admin" for everything unless you plan on rolling out your own version of the "sudo" command

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice guess I have to re-do my entire application security. I was basically checking localstorage for updating,deleting and modifying items on my page based on if the users id that they signed in on was equal to the one in localstorage. Thought localstorage would be enough.

Comment: be aware JWT is insecure if you dont use SSL, there are many layers to protect rest/socket services, one cannot just trust clientside state

Comment: @LawrenceCherone everything is insecure if you do not use SSL, even cookies. A rule of thumb is, if it's behind a login screen use SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the tasks are created before hand then each should be handed a unique Immutable ID. To implement this in Javascript use:

```
Object.freeze()
```

According to Mozilla Developer Network:

> The Object.freeze() method freezes an object: that is, prevents new properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed, it also prevents the prototype from being changed. The method returns the passed object.

A link to the documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Comment: While that will work for creating a fixed ID, it doesn't prevent the user from manipulating local storage or sending falsified data to the server.

Comment: This wouldn't prevent the user from blocking that line of code, either, right?

Comment: @AdamHess Each task has an ID which is immutable! This comes with a default validation. Any attempt to change the tasks ID will result in an error.
See example logic:

`const TASKID = {task1: "laundry" `
};

const FREEZETASKID = Object.freeze(task1);

FREEZETASKID.task1 = "Wash Dishes";
// Throws an error in strict mode

console.log(FREEZETASKID.task1);
// expected output: "laundry"

@JudeDesir Blocking the line of code will affect the entire build!

Comment: How do you ensure that the ID is the same on both the server and client and that the user will not send garbage data?  On top of that, you can manipulate local resources via developer tools not just javascript.